# undefined method `entry_mapping' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, minitest, roda

I am trying to play around with the RODA Ruby web framework based on Rack. However, I am having issues with using `Minitest` with the framework. RSpec was hectic with it too unlike Rails. I tried to reproduce the error with pry, but I couldn't make sense of it. How should I fix this? I am getting

> undefined method `entry_mapping' for nil:NilClass.

Below is the associated code:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'contentful_model', '~> 1.3'           # ActiveModel-like wrapper for the Contentful SDKs


group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'minitest', '>= 5.7.0'
  gem 'minitest-hooks', '>= 1.1.0'
  gem "minitest-global_expectations"
  gem "warning"
  gem 'pry'
end
```

**models/recipe.rb**

```
require 'contentful_model'

class Recipe < ContentfulModel::Base
  self.content_type_id = 'recipe'

  def self.all_recipes
    all.load!
  end
end
```

**app.rb** | **Tree Routing**

```
require './.env' if File.exist?(".env.rb")
require './config/initializers/contentful_model'
require 'roda'
require './models/recipe'
require 'tilt/sass'

class App < Roda
  hash_routes do
    view '', 'index'
  end

  route do |r|
    @recipes = Recipe.all_recipes

    r.public
    r.assets
    check_csrf!
    r.hash_routes('')

    r.get String do |id|
      @recipe_details = Recipe.find(id)
      next unless @recipe_details
      view 'show'
    end
  end
end
```

**spec/models/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = "test"
require_relative '../../models/recipe'

require_relative '../minitest_helper'
```

**spec/models/recipe_spec.rb**

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe Recipe do
  let(:recipes) { Recipe.all_recipes }
  describe '.all_recipes' do
    it 'return all records with content type recipe' do
      recipes = Recipe.all_recipes # undefined method `entry_mapping' for nil:NilClass
      expect(recipes).to all must_be Recipe
    end
  end
end
```

**pry debug**

```
From: /Users/tiwa/RubymineProjects/marley-spoon-roda/spec/models/recipe_spec.rb:27 .all_recipes#test_0001_return all records with content type recipe:

    24: it 'return all records with content type recipe' do
    25:   recipes = Recipe.all_recipes # undefined method `entry_mapping' for nil:NilClass
    26:   binding.pry
 => 27:   expect(recipes).to all must_be Recipe
    28: end

[1] pry(#<.all_recipes>)> Recipe.all_recipes
NoMethodError: undefined method `entry_mapping' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/tiwa/.gem/ruby/2.7.1/gems/contentful_model-1.3.0/lib/contentful_model/base.rb:124:in `mapping?'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the code in **contentful_model-1.3.0/lib/contentful_model/base.rb:124** is:

```rb
ContentfulModel.configuration.entry_mapping.key?(@content_type_id)
```

If error msg is `` undefined method `entry_mapping' for nil:NilClass `` then

```rb
ContentfulModel.configuration
```

**Is nil**

To fix this you need configure ContentfulModel. Something like that:

```rb
ContentfulModel.configure do |config|
  config.access_token = "your access token in here" # Required
  config.preview_access_token = "your preview token in here" # Optional - required if you want to use the preview API
  config.management_token = "your management token in here" # Optional - required if you want to update or create content
  config.space = "your space id in here" # Required
  config.environment = "master" # Optional - defaults to 'master'
  config.default_locale = "en-US" # Optional - defaults to 'en-US'
  config.options = { # Optional
    # Extra options to send to the Contentful::Client and Contentful::Management::Client
    # See https://github.com/contentful/contentful.rb#configuration

    # Optional:
    # Use `delivery_api` and `management_api` keys to limit to what API the settings
    # will apply. Useful because Delivery API is usually visitor facing, while Management
    # is used in background tasks that can run much longer. For example:
    delivery_api: {
      timeout_read: 6
    },
    management_api: {
      timeout_read: 100
    }
  }
end
```

With this config this call is not more nil

```rb
ContentfulModel.configuration
```

See https://github.com/contentful/contentful_model

Comment: But if it is `ContentfulModel.configuration` actually nil, it will not pull my API. API responds as expected.

Comment: Except this means, I need to set `ContentfulModel.configuration` for my test environment

Comment: Yes you need set on each environment. @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi